# Using __annotations__ as parameter options for a function in a class

Tags: python, oop, inspect

I have a parent class which should set function parameters for init function in child class using **annotations**.
So:

```
class Parent:
    # check for annotations and set them for __init__ function

class Child(Parent):
    a: int
    b: int
    c: float
```

So, when inspecting the Child class, IDE should display:
[image]

I tried to use inspect and signature, but my attempts failed so far.
Is there a proper way to implement this to help IDEs for inspection? I've seen something similar in BaseModel of pydantic.

Comment: So basically I am doing it for IDE purposes

Comment: Have you tried just using the `dataclasses` standard library module? Does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [get_type_hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) from `typing`:

```py
from typing import get_type_hints


class Child(Parent):
    a: int
    b: int
    c: float


get_type_hints(Parent)
# {'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'int'>, 'c': <class 'float'>}
```

[getmro()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=mro#inspect.getmro) from `introspection` may be useful in case of inheritance.

Comment: I need to set those typehints for child class init function.. i'm already using class.__annotations__

Comment: oh, sorry
For such case I have only one idea - to generate [.pyi stubs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files) with `__init__` signature completed  from typehints.